# Sum of even rows

Tags: powershell

I am new in PowerShell and i would like to get a program that sum, the even rows from a text file for example:

```
12 12
14 15
13 14
```

14+15=29

I have already tried the `get-content | measure -sum` , but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following assuming your text file is named `sum.txt`:

```
Get-Content sum.txt -ReadCount 2 |
    Where Count -eq 2 |
        Foreach-Object {
            $numbers = $_[-1] -split ' '
            [int]$numbers[0] + [int]$numbers[1]
        }
```

**Explanation:**

The `-ReadCount 2` property reads in two lines at a time and passes those two lines as an object into the pipeline.

The `Where {}` block is to prevent the last line from outputting if it is an odd numbered line.

`$_` is the current pipeline object in the `Foreach-Object` block. Since two lines are passed in, `$_[-1]` will return the last line of the two.

`-split ' '` separates the two numbers into an array because they are space-separated. Since `-split` returns a string, we need to cast each number as a numeric type (`[int]`) in order to perform the addition.

Comment: Thank you for your help!